# Use tar to exclude one directory (but not another) that matches a pattern

Tags: linux, unix, bash, tar, exclude

I'm working on doing a pretty straightforward tar for a site, but there's a wrinkle. Here's the file structure of the site:

> ...
>   files/
>   images/
>   images/visitors/
>   ...
>   logs/
>   ...
>   visitors/

Here's the problem: I want to exclude all the files in the main visitors/ directory, **but I want all the files in the images/visitors/ directory to be included** in the tarball.

I've been trying `tar c --exclude-from='excludeList'` with the following as the content of "excludeList":

> excludeList
>   files/
>   visitors/

Unfortunately, since the files in images/visitors/ match the visitors/ pattern, they're excluded, too. In a perfect world, I could go regex with something like this:

> excludeList
>   files/
>   ^visitors/

But that doesn't work. Is there any way to make this work, either straight through tar or with another sort of pattern-matching command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `--anchored` option.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks! This page was helpful: http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/controlling-pattern_002dmatching.html

Comment: It seems `--anchored` must come _before_ `--exclude-from=` and `--exclude=`!